# Symfony is linked to the wrong PHP version

Tags: php, symfony, redhat

I'm trying to move my Project to a linux redhat server that uses Apache but the problem I'm facing there is that this Server has 2 different PHP versions installed.

Symfony (2.5.12) seems to look for the php executable at `/usr/bin/php` by default but there is a 5.2 version installed, which is needed for other projects.

At `/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin/php` is an installed 5.5 version of PHP that I want to use for symfony.

So how can I configure Symfony to use the php version that is installed at the custom path?

Comment: I assume you're talking about the symfony command line tool is using `/usr/bin/php`?

Comment: You can invoke command line files such as the console using the full path of the PHP executable such as: `/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin/php app/console namespace:command`

Comment: First question to ask: Why does the box have two PHP versions installed. Remove the 5.2 version, and make sure that when `php` is invoked at the command-line, it runs 5.5.

Comment: As an aside, to determine which PHP executable is being executed, type `which php` into the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's your web application that's using the wrong version of PHP, this is an Apache configuration issue. If it's the command line, this is actually a pretty easy thing to fix, you just need to make sure that `/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin/` is in your `$PATH` before `/usr/bin`.

You can do this in your `~/.bashrc` or  `~/.bash_profile` with this:

```
export PATH=/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Just put that at the end, log out and in again. You can also just pop that in your command line directly, but it'll only apply for the current session, so the `~/.bashrc` or  `~/.bash_profile` options are better.

Comment: Your answer is correct. My question is nonsense because I thought it's posible to configure such things in symfony but it was just an apache configuration issue. However, I thought my current symfony exception where caused by an outdated php version but it seems it isn't.

Comment: @MayaK Bummer. Good luck tracking the issue. Feel free to post another question if you need help. *If you're happy with any of the answers you've seen, click the tick beside the answer*

Answer (score 72):

I know this is old, but I had the same issue of Symfony using an older PHP version (7.1 in my case, the default with OSX Mojave) than I had installed. My `$PATH` variable pointed to the newer 7.2 version and `php -v` showed 7.2 and still Symfony used 7.1.

It looks like this was solved when I ran:

```
symfony local:php:list
```

It listed all the PHP versions on my system and it had 7.2 marked as default. After running this and executing `symfony server:start` it was on 7.2.

The `php:list` command also give useful instructions on setting a specific PHP version for a project:

> To control the version used in a directory, create a `.php-version` file that contains the version number (e.g. 7.2 or 7.2.15).
>   If you're using SymfonyCloud, the version can also be specified in the `.symfony.cloud.yaml` file.

Comment: This was the solution for me, under Windows 10. Multiple PHP CGI exes installed and Symfony defaulted to the wrong one until I ran symfony local:php:list, which seemed to default it to the correct version.

Comment: Just to add, somehow running `symfony local:php:refresh` fixed the issue, then I could run `symfony server:start` as usual.

Comment: I did `symfony local:php:list` but it doesn't show all the php versions on my system, only the ones of wamp64 and xampp whereas I have other versions in C:/php/ . I also did the refresh command but it doesn't fix it. Any idea ?

Comment: @Eve You have to have all of them in your environment path. That is how they get auto-discovered.

Comment: Thank you @informatik-handwerk.de , I didn't test that.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when I did `symfony serve`.

First I ran `symfony local:php:list` to know which version of php my project used.

Then I ran `echo 7.4.9 > .php-version` (7.4.9 is the latest php version I downloaded) to switch the php version of my project.

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Go into the command line interface and type below command if you want to upgrade into PHP 8.1.6 from 7.4.22

echo 8.1.6 > .php-version

it will create a .php-version file that contains the version number (8.1.6)

then try to run

symfony local:php:refresh

this is it then

Answer (score 1):

After installing PHP 7.4.16, when trying to start my server:

```
symfony server:start
```

I was getting the following error:

```
exec: "/usr/local/bin/php": stat /usr/local/bin/php: no such file or directory
```

After running

```
symfony local:php:list
```

found that:

```
┌─────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Version │ Directory  │  PHP CLI   │ PHP FPM │ PHP CGI │ Server  │ System? │
├─────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 7.4.14  │ /usr/local │ bin/php    │         │         │ PHP CLI │ *       │
│ 7.4.16  │ /usr       │ bin/php7.4 │         │         │ PHP CLI │         │
└─────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

As it turns out I had some leftover files from a previous installation of PHP 7.4.14 and Symfony was trying to still use that version, which was already removed.
After removing `php-config, phpize and phpdbg` files at `/usr/local/bin` I could run my server without problems.

Answer (score 0):

go to your project
create a .php-version file that contains the version number (8.1.0)