# Symfony framework cannot use homebrew installed php

Tags: php, macos, symfony

I am using Brew to install latest php version, and it works in my terminal:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.3.7 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2019 12:44:05) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.7, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.7, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

But when I create a new symfony framework project, and run `symfony server:start`, it shows me that symfony using the old php7.1, but the installed latest php is 7.3.

```
$symfony server:start

 [WARNING] run "symfony server:ca:install" first if you want to run the web server
 with TLS support, or use "--no-tls" to avoid this warning


Jul 31 19:21:51 |DEBUG| PHP    Using PHP version 7.1.23 (from default version in $PATH)
```

the message shows it using php 7.1.23 from $PATH as default version, so I delete the php7.1.23 from the $PATH, and link php7.3 to the $PATH, but still not work

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482664/symfony-is-linked-to-the-wrong-php-version

Comment: HINT: `from default version in $PATH`

Comment: @RiggsFolly how symfony find the default version? the php7.3 is in my $PATH too, and it works fine in the normal terminal environment. why symfony skip the php7.3 and choice the 7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `symfony local:php:list` to see a list of all php versions installed.  To use a specific version, you can create a `.php-version` file that contains the version number.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite some time after but a fix the same problem in Windows 10 was to change the .php-version codification file to UTF8 (e.g. with notepad++).