# Brew install php "Version 7.3.9_1"

Tags: php

I installed php via brew on Mac...
Looks like the version number is not correct or is this real?
"v7.3.9_1" is the current version

```
brew install php
```

Comment: Install dir is "/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.9_1"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony framework cannot use homebrew installed php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289780/symfony-framework-cannot-use-homebrew-installed-php)

Comment: what's the output of `brew info php` `php -v`, `phpinfo()` and `which php`?