# Symfony 5.4.9 Composer detected issues in your platform:

Tags: php, symfony

I am totally new to Symfony. After I installed Symfony on my local ddev machine, I get this error

```
Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 7.4.29. in /var/www/html/symfony/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24
```

I tried to `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` as well, and soon as I run it, I get this error message

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/symfony/vendor/psr/log/src/LoggerInterface.php on line 30
```

My php version is

```
❯ php -v
PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 12 2022 23:44:22) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Compose.json

```
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.17|^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/runtime": "*",
        "symfony/yaml": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "config": {
```

Thanks for help

## Update

If you are using docker/ddev, make sure to set the php version inside `config.yml`

Make sure to php version matches the symfony requirements

```
name: ddev-gitpod
type: drupal9
docroot: web
php_version: "8.1"
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
database:
  type: mariadb
  version: "10.3"
nfs_mount_enabled: false
mutagen_enabled: false
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: ""
web_environment: []
nodejs_version: "16"
```

Comment: Change `php: ">=7.2.5` to `php: ">=8.1` in your `composer.json` file and update. Your project is probably running on an older 7.4 version you once used and still have installed even if you also have php 8.1 installed in your computer. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55905650/17089665)

Comment: How did you install Symfony?  Your error message does not make sense.  5.4 only need PHP 7.2.5 yet you somehow have newer software that requires a later version?  Have you been editing composer.json?  Make a new project and just do clean install using the Symfony CLI.  You also seem to have multiple PHP versions on your machine.  Do as craigh suggests below to ensure Symfony is using the expected version though that is only part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit these 2 things in your composer.json to solve your problem :

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
}
```

And

```
"config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "8.1.6"
        },
    },
```

Comment: Well no.  Just no.  I know you are trying to help and I promise this will be the last time I comment on one of your posts.  You can't just toss stuff out there with no explanation especially if they have no chance of working.  The Symfony 5.4.9 composer.json file does not even have a config platform section and changing the main php dependency will not fix anything and indeed will probably break other stuff.  The OP probably has multiple PHP versions installed and they have probably manually edited composer.json or did an unconventional install.  Perhaps an upgrade.

Comment: we'll see, time will tell

Comment: Actually this helped. After that I updated composer, and is working

Comment: Thanks you @balrcoding ! And see you Cerad ;) (don't worry I do not hold grudges)

Answer (score 3):

Run this command:

```
symfony local:php:list
```

You will get some output listing the various versions of php you have installed on your computer and the one being used by the `symfony` binary will be highlighted. There will also be instructions on how to control the version used by the binary:

> To control the version used in a directory, create a .php-version file that contains the version number (e.g. 7.2 or 7.2.15).

Answer (score 0):

I got the exactly the same errors in my Laravel fresh install.

My local server env is Vagrant Ubuntu Nginx. And I have multiple php versions installes in my local. To list:

```
$ update-alternatives --display php
```

Check the php cli version:

```
$ php -v
```

Then create a info.php file and see the project runing php version
`<?php echo phpinfo();`

There will be 2 different version.

So I changed the project runing php version via Nginx vhost file:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/your-file-name
```

Edit the line to your required php version, and that version has to be installed in your server. So in this case, edit the below line in vhost file:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}
```

Make sure the php version file path is correct and it is available in your given directory. In my case it is /var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock