# Symfony update 5.4 to 6.1

Tags: php, symfony

I update symfony version 5.4 to 6.1, I have this error and I can't find the solution on the forum (I think that there are several problems in same time):

```
Fatal error: Declaration of App\Repository\UserRepository::upgradePassword(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface $user, string $newEncodedPassword): void must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordUpgraderInterface::upgradePassword(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface $user, string $newHashedPassword): void in /Users/pjf/sites/myapp/src/Repository/UserRepository.php on line 29
```

In my app:

```
Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 7.4.30. in /Users/pfjsites/myapp/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24
```

My file composer.json:

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "php": ">=8.1",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.3",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.9",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^1.2",
    "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^4.0",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^5.8",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.2",
    "symfony/asset": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/console": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/intl": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/mime": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/notifier": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/process": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/property-access": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/property-info": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/runtime": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/serializer": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/string": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/translation": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/validator": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "6.1.*",
    "twbs/bootstrap-icons": "^1.9",
    "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
    "twig/intl-extra": "^3.3",
    "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/css-selector": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.36",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "6.1.*",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.1.*"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true,

    "platform-check": false

},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "6.1.*"
    }
},

"platform": {
 "php": "8.1.6"}}}
```

I add some code
([Symfony 5.4.9 Composer detected issues in your platform:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72572584/symfony-5-4-9-composer-detected-issues-in-your-platform))

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=8.1",
```

}

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "8.1.6"
    },
},
```

How to solve? Thank in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Please share the code you are using that triggers the problem. Also, I'll remove the tags from this question that are unrelated

Comment: Symfony 6.1 requires PHP 8.1.  Do you still have deprecations in your 5.4 app?  The error you have is the sort of thing that would have generated a notice in 5.4.  In general you should fix the notices before trying to upgrade.

Comment: I have also found it to be a bit problematical to edit an existing composer.json file when going to a new major version.  If you create a new 6.1 project you can see that doctrine versions need some adjusting and that you also have a couple of symfony version errors.  If you then require your third party stuff you will see other version issues.  dompdf for example is now at 2.0 instead of 1.2.  Any of these issues can cause further problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages already contain the answers, the signatures of some methods changed and need to be adjusted in your custom code to be "compatible" with the new symfony version

go to UserRepository.php on line 29

and change the $user parameter from

```
(UserInterface $user, string $newEncodedPassword)
```

to

```
(PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface $user, string $newHashedPassword)
```

at the top of the file "use" the interface to not write the full path in method like above:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
```

The other message just says that your app requires php-version 8.1 minimum but you are running 7.4.30, so you need to upgrade php on the system where you run your app.